# How do I subquery this in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql

Calculate the minimum salary for exempt employees and the average salary for non-exempt employees in a SINGLE SQL statement. Use subqueries to incorporate both elements in the query. It should look something like:

```
Min Exempt Salary   Average Non-Exempt Salary
47,000                           35,271
```

I know how to do it separate but cannot figure how to do it as it stated above , this is the statments I have.

```
SELECT jobs1.exempt_nonexempt_status,
       Min (employees.salary)AS Minimal_Exempt_Salary
FROM   employees
       LEFT JOIN jobs1
              ON employees.job_title = jobs1.job_title
WHERE  jobs1.exempt_nonexempt_status = 'Exempt'
GROUP  BY jobs1.exempt_nonexempt_status

SELECT jobs1.exempt_nonexempt_status,
       Avg (employees.salary)AS Average_Non_Exempt_Salary
FROM   employees
       LEFT JOIN jobs1
              ON employees.job_title = jobs1.job_title
WHERE  jobs1.exempt_nonexempt_status = 'Non-exempt'
GROUP  BY jobs1.exempt_nonexempt_status
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A normal way to do this would be:

```
select  j.exempt_nonexempt_status
,       avg(case when j.exempt_nonexempt_status='Non-exempt' then e.salary end) 
            as Average_Non_Exempt_Salary
,       min(case when j.exempt_nonexempt_status='Exempt' then e.salary end)
            as Minimal_Exempt_Salary
from    Employees e 
left join 
        jobs1 j
on      e.job_title = j.job_title
group by 
        j.exempt_nonexempt_status
```

But that doesn't use subqueries.  Another way is to wrap your two queries in an outer select:

```
select  (
        select MIN (employees.salary)
        from Employees left join jobs1
        on employees.job_title = jobs1.job_title
        where jobs1.exempt_nonexempt_status='Exempt'
        group by jobs1.exempt_nonexempt_status
        ) as MinimalExemptSalary
,       (
        select avg (employees.salary)
        from Employees left join jobs1
        on employees.job_title = jobs1.job_title
        where jobs1.exempt_nonexempt_status='Non-exempt'
        group by jobs1.exempt_nonexempt_status
        ) as AverageNonExemptSalary
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    MIN(CASE WHEN J.exempt_nonexempt_status = 'Exempt'
             THEN E.Salary
             END) AS Minimal_Exempt_Salary,

    SUM(CASE WHEN J.exempt_nonexempt_status = 'Non-exempt'
             THEN E.Salary
             END) AS Average_Non_Exempt_Salary

FROM Employees E
LEFT JOIN JOBS1 J ON J.job_title = E.job_title
WHERE J.exempt_nonexempt_status IN ('Exempt', 'Non-exempt')
```

Comment: It's better to use `null` than a magic number like `9999999999999`.  Since the default value of a `case` is `null`, you can omit the `else` clause entirely.  And you could use the `avg` aggregate instead of the calculation with two `sum`s.

Comment: Thank you so much , I was over thinking this.